# how does one index array in rospy?

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, rospy, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need the size of a custom array msg type. (The type is geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[] PoseStampedArray.)
I need to iterate on the msg if it is not empty and I would very much like to get the last element without iterating on the whole thing.

I must be missing something because these look like basic things one should be able to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359824/how-does-one-index-array-in-rospy?/) by [gbohus](https://answers.ros.org/users/58051/gbohus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I need to iterate on the msg if it is not empty and I would very much like to get the last element without iterating on the whole thing.

You ask about `rospy`, which would make this Python.

As you can see on [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields) (which documents the ROS 1 msg IDL and how it gets mapped to various programming languages), a field of type `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[]` will be mapped to a Python `tuple` (ie: a tuple of `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` instances, as many as were put in the array byt the sender).

For your use you can just consider that a `list`, and accessing the last element of a list can be done as follows in Python (`my_msg` is an instance of a message with `pose_list` being a field of type `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[]`):

```
last_element = my_msg.pose_list[-1]
```

Iteration would be as you would normally do this with Python:

```
for elem in my_msg.pose_list:
    # do something
```

Note: this is not ROS specific at all. It's all just Python.

> I must be missing something because these look like basic things one should be able to do.

The reason you cannot find any specific documentation about this is because it isn't something ROS changes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gbohus](https://answers.ros.org/users/58051/gbohus/) on 2020-08-19**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn.

My mistake was not to look *inside* the message, but trying to iterate on/access the elements of the message itself.